# How to get comma-separated values from select query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get comma separated ID list from select Query data in SQL Server 2008.
Do you have any ideas about it.

Comment: Not very much to go on - **show us** your table structures, **show us** what ***YOU*** have tried so far, tell us where you're stuck, where you have problems.....

Comment: thanks for replay.. i have query like "select iID from tablename" we  get id list but i want to get this ids in comma separated value. for example from select query i got IDs 1 2 3 4 5 in grid structure but i want "1,2,3,4,5" like this in comma separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set results format in Management Studio:

```
tools>option>query results>sql server>results to test>output format
```